# Switch method : why is num giving me 'num is unknown'?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

```js
function testNum(a) {
  switch (a) {
    case a > 0:
      alert("positif num");
      break;
    case a < 0:
      alert("num is negative");
      break;
    default:
      alert("num is unknown");
  }
}

testNum(4);
```

So im trying to do this simple if statement with Swtich methods and smh simply not working the way i want,why its not giving me 'num is positive' , ???

Comment: The case expressions are evaluated, and then `a` is *compared* to the resulting values. 4 is not equal to `true`.

Comment: You should be using an `if` statement not a `switch` statement

Comment: yeah i know i could use if statement,i want to know how to it with switch,thx guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch in javascript evaluate an expression and not a number ... The common workaround is to use

```
 switch(true){

 }
```

see below :

```js
function testNum(a) {
  switch (true) {
    case a > 0:
      alert("positif num");
      break;
    case a < 0:
      alert("num is negative");
      break;
    default:
      alert("num is unknown");
  }
}

testNum(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use condition in case use If or this way

```
function testNum(a) {
  switch (true) {
    case a > 0:
      alert("positif num");
      break;
    case a < 0:
      alert("num is negative");
      break;
    default:
      alert("num is unknown");
  }
}

testNum(4)
```